# Lines containing given word in output file C

Tags: c, file

I am very new to working with files and I can't seem to get my head around this. What I am trying to do is to write in the *Exit.txt* file all the lines that have my given word in them. For example, if my word is "**exercise**" and my *In.txt* contains the following:

```
I exercise daily
I like apples
How often do you exercise
I am tired
```

Then in *Exit.txt* I should have

```
I exercise daily
How often do you exercise
```

The problem is that somehow it only writes the last line in the *Exit.txt* file, and sometimes it doesn't even write anything, depending on my input *In.txt*.

I would very much appreciate any help, thank you very much!

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<string.h>

    int main()
    {
      FILE* fis, * fis2;
      char* sir, * rez, word[50];
    printf("Word: ");
        gets(word);
    sir = malloc(50 * sizeof(char));
    fis = fopen("In.txt", "rt");
    if (fis == NULL)
        printf("Can't open file!");
    else
    {
        while (!feof(fis))
        {
            rez = fgets(sir, 50, fis);
                if (strcmp(rez,word)==0)
                {
                    fis2 = fopen("Exit.txt", "wt");
                    fputs(sir, fis2);
                }
        }
    }
    fclose(fis);
    free(sir);
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: You need to read this: [**Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: NEVER use `gets`. Use `fgets` instead

Answer (score 0):

When you open a file for writing in a loop you must know about the offset. Its better open file in append mode, write your data and close it.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<string.h>

int main()
{
    FILE* fis, * fis2;
    char* sir, * rez, word[50];
    char *line = NULL;
    ssize_t bufsiz = 0;
    ssize_t nbytes;
  
    printf("Word: ");
    gets(word);
    fis = fopen("In.txt", "rt");
    if (fis == NULL)
        printf("Can't open file!");
    else
    {
        while ((nbytes = getline(&line, &bufsiz, fis)) != -1)
        {
            char * ptr_value = strstr(line,word);
            if(ptr_value != NULL) {
                printf(line);
                fis2 = fopen("Exit.txt", "a");
                fputs(line, fis2);
                fclose(fis2);               
            }       
        }       
    }
    fclose(fis);
    return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

there are a few changes needed to get your code working:

- only open the output file once (so not in the while loop)
- to check if a string is a part of another string please use "strstr" and not "strcmp"
- don't forget to close your file at the end

So here is a suggestion for a solution

```
int main()
{
    FILE* fis, * fis2;
    char* sir, * rez, word[50];
    printf("Word: ");
    gets(word);
    sir = malloc(50 * sizeof(char));
    fis = fopen("In.txt", "rt");
    if (fis == NULL)
        printf("Can't open file!");
    if ((fis2 = fopen("Exit.txt","wt"))==NULL){
        printf("Cant't open Exit-file\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    else
    {
        while (!feof(fis))
        {
            rez = fgets(sir, 50, fis);
            if(strstr(rez,word)!=NULL)
            {
                fputs(sir, fis2);
            }
        }
    }
fclose(fis);
fclose(fis2);
free(sir);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong